# Tips for writing an algorithm for paraphrasing sentences(machine learning)

Tags: machine-learning, text, word2vec, linguistics

I am doing a project at the university and I need to train an algorithm to rephrase sentences, what can you advise for implementation? Is it possible to use a translator to translate into another language in the end to get a paraphrased sentence? Also i want to use Word2Vec, or it's a bad idea?

Comment: This question is too vague and broad in scope for SO. This site is for **specific questions** related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. You may want to spend some time reviewing the [help] pages to better understand what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before your next post.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of broad-advice question – and about a very-tough problem, paraphrasing text, that is still a very active research problem – would be better answered by surveyin the research literature.

A great site for searching relevant papers – and then finding other related papers once you've set some positive examples – is http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/.

Searching for [paraphrasing] or [summarization] would give you a running start in seeing major techniques & their limitations. And, once you start bookmarking papers by the little 'disk' icon, it can autosuggest important related papers... so even if your 1st few finds are tangential or far-from-usefulness, it can lead you to the seminal papers, & prevailing cutting-edge algorithms/libraries, pretty quickly.